# Pandas and Pycharm unresolved references

Tags: python, pandas

```
name = 'Name'
address = 'Address'

def function():
    condition = (dataframe[column] = name) & (dataframe[column] = address)
```

I want to filter a dataframe by first creating a condition variable that will be used to filter the column values. However, it gives me an Unreseolved References error message? I am not really sure why..

Comment: Can you try `condition = (dataframe[column] == name) & (dataframe[column] == address)`? Otherwise you might be encountering a syntax error.

Comment: == instead of =

Comment: `dataframe[column] = name` must be `dataframe[column] == name`. (Same with address.) Also, has  the variable `column` been defined?

Comment: I tried condition = (dataframe[column] == name) & (dataframe[column] == address) and it worked perfectly!! thank you so much